# Implementar OnClick en Image

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy haciendo un proyecto(un juego de memoria) con este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChrWz8ZMyOU 
Lo estoy haciendo un poco diferente 
 Cree un menu_activity que dice el nombre del juego y una imagen con el icono Play.
Esto nos lleva a la segunda actividad, donde esta el problema tengo 3 imágenes 
que nos indican la dificultad.

En el proyecto no me aparece ningún error,  me corre pero al momento de ir a mi LevelActivity y hacer click en la dificultad,por ejemplo para ir EasyActivity(y que muestre el memorama) la aplicación no hace nada. No se mucho sobre el tema pero creo que es un problema al momento de implementar el OnClick. Trate de crear el OnClick como lo hice con el menu principal:

```
public void goGame(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LevelActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Pero al hacer esto y dar click en la dificultad se cierra la aplicacion.
Les muestro parte del código.

El LevelActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LevelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);
}
}
```

El XML de la imagen que nos indica la dificultad

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/easylevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/facil"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />
```

Tengo mi clase EasyActivity

```
public class EasyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener { 

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);
```

//Me salte el codigo que considero no afecta al problema

```
for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < numColumns; c++){
            MemoryButton tempButton = new MemoryButton(this, r, c, 
buttonGraphics[buttonGraphicLocations[r * numColumns + c]]);
            tempButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
            tempButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttons[r * numColumns + c] = tempButton;
             gridLayout.addView(tempButton);
        }
    }
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {....}
```

Comment: Usa el método onClick y detecta cuando un elemento fue activado por medio de su id, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu `Activity` implementa `OnClickListener`, debes implementar `onClick()` y puedes detectar cuando el `ImageView` fue activado por medio de su id, de esta forma:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view){
     switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.easylevel: //id de ImageView.

        //realiza operación al dar clic al imageView.
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, LevelActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);

         break;
        default:
         break;
     }
   }
```